# I am getting error says ; expected Please have alook at my code

Tags: selenium

I am trying to create a checktext method which takes option and String [] values, but I am getting and error ; expected right after for(option : resultlist) its a for statement I am not sure why its expecting ;

```
public static void checktext(WebElement option , String [] validvalues){
    List<WebElement> resultlist = ElementFinder.findAll(RESULTS_CONTAINER);
    for ( option : resultlist)
    {


        if (validvalues.equals(option.getText())||validvalues.equals(option.getText())||validvalues.equals(option.getText()))
        {
            ElementFinder.clickOnElementWithRetry(option);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Assert.fail(option.getText()+"Does not match the listed value");
        }
    }

}
public static void clickAndVerifyResults() throws Exception {
    String [] validvalues = {"Win-Draw-Win", "Draw No Bet", "Correct Score"};
    ElementFinder. waitUntilElementIsVisible(RESULTS_CONTAINER);
    List<WebElement> resultlist = ElementFinder.findAll(RESULTS_CONTAINER);
    checktext(option, validvalues);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a type for option.

```
for (WebElement option: reslutlist)
```